# Decoding `democracy.Voted`

Tags: polkadot, scale

I'm having trouble decoding a `democracy.Voted` event on Polkadot - for example: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frpc.polkadot.io#/explorer/query/0x960b817cc1d137151ec6069753f7458fbdd6fb26dbff3888137ae8b09b4fc060

I'm working in Golang and I suspect that I am unpacking into a wrongly-defined data stucture.

As I understand it, `democracy.Voted` is comprised of:

- `AccountId32` - underlying data type is a 32 byte array
- `ReferendumIndex` - underlying data type is an unsigned 32 bit integer
- `PalletDemocracyVoteAccountVote` - described [here](https://crates.parity.io/pallet_democracy/struct.Vote.html)

In Rust, the Vote data structure is:

```rs
pub struct Vote {
    pub aye: bool,
    pub conviction: Conviction,
}
```

I think I am having trouble with the `Conviction` enum.

I notice in block explorers (e.g. [here](https://polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/0xf5316f9dae9e650deb08e5e72c07ea37984a076aeb9b6826b8724b6c21b283e6)) that the `Vote` is reported as what looks like a U8 integer - in the case of the example above, 128.

1. What is the underlying type for `Conviction`?
2. Are the variants for `Conviction` determined by a bitfield on a single byte?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `aye` (bool) & `conviction` (enum) is encoded together as a single byte. The top-most bit indicated the true/false, the remaining bits indicates the conviction.

You can look here for the specific [Vote decoding code](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/42044053b5895991d06ddc776e45da61c6462c78/frame/democracy/src/vote.rs#L44-L53) -

```rust
impl Decode for Vote {
    fn decode<I: Input>(input: &mut I) -> Result<Self, codec::Error> {
        let b = input.read_byte()?;
        Ok(Vote {
            aye: (b & 0b1000_0000) == 0b1000_0000,
            conviction: Conviction::try_from(b & 0b0111_1111)
                .map_err(|_| codec::Error::from("Invalid conviction"))?,
        })
    }
}
```

So in your example, 128 would be an aye with [no conviction](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/42044053b5895991d06ddc776e45da61c6462c78/frame/democracy/src/conviction.rs#L31-L46).

Comment: In case someone is not familiar with the binary system/bitwise operations/bit masking, maybe this hackmd [Decoding vote lock up periods](https://hackmd.io/@LwMsxe3-SFmNXxugAXOKgg/SJ0Ulylyh) will be helpful. It explains in more detail the above code.